# Is there a way to plot graphs in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, plot, graph

**To begin with:** I am working on image processing in OpenCV C++.

**The Requirement** is to plot a graph out of the Vector values of a 1D image. I referred http://answers.opencv.org/question/73233/how-do-you-plot-graphs-in-opencv-projects/  and found a solution for it. It is a brilliant one that one could make in OpenCV but, the `plot` is not recognized by the OpenCV original libraries.

**To find a solution** for this, I went through all the library files and came to a conclusion that the header file
          `#include opencv2/plot.hpp`  is not in the original OpenCV library(latest version). It must be implemented in some additional library but hasn't been on live I suppose.

Here is my **CODE** for your reference:

```
#include <opencv2/plot.hpp>

int PlotGraph(Mat & data) {


Mat plot_result;

Ptr<plot::Plot2d> plot = plot::createPlot2d(data);

//Set Background color
plot->setPlotBackgroundColor(Scalar(50, 50, 50)); 

//Set plot line color
plot->setPlotLineColor(Scalar(50, 50, 255));
plot->render(plot_result);

imshow("plot", plot_result);
waitKey();

plot->setPlotLineColor(Scalar(50, 255, 255));
data = data / 3;
plot->render(plot_result);

imshow("plot", plot_result);
waitKey();

plot->setPlotGridColor(Scalar(255, 0, 255));
data = data * 4;
plot->render(IMREAD_UNCHANGEDplot_result);

imshow("plot", plot_result);
waitKey();

plot->setPlotTextColor(Scalar(255, 0, 0));
randu(data, 100, 400);
plot->render(plot_result);

imshow("plot", plot_result);
waitKey();

return 0;

}
```

There are many ways in C++ and other libraries such as GNU to plot graphs but, I am being bit curious and not want to give up on this.

I would appreciate if anyone gives me a solution to this or suggest a way to plot graphs in OpenCV C++.

Comment: The plot module is in the _contrib modules_. You need to rebuild OpenCV to use it

Comment: this plot library is in [opencv contrib library](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib), other than that one, there is no direct way of doing it, manually you can do it, if you see the examples of [histogram calculation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html), you will see line plot there... Nevertheless, I would recommend to use any other library for this purpose, since OpenCV alternatives usually look pretty bad

Comment: Alright guys, thank you. Looks like there is a additional setup process to add the contributing modules. I will try doing that and also take into account that there are better libraries to plot graphs.

Comment: you can test it without compiling contrib module. [here is the test code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sturkmen72/opencv_samples/master/plot-test.cpp)

Comment: @sturkmen please have a look at my answer below. Thanks for your awesome solution.

Comment: @sturkmen Is there a way to scale the graph?

Comment: you can use `setMinX`,`setMinY`,`setMaxX`,`setMaxY` i think change of these values works to scale the graph.

Comment: Ptr<plot::Plot2d> plot = plot::Plot2d::create(data);
plot->setPlotBackgroundColor(Scalar(50, 50, 50)); 
plot->setPlotLineColor(Scalar(50, 50, 255));
plot->setMinX(0);
plot->setMinY(0);
plot->setMaxX(4000);
plot->setMaxY(1000);

plot->render(plot_result);          

imshow("Graph", plot_result);
waitKey();

return 0;
}

Comment: @sturkmen including the above codes doesn't scale the graph. Is this what you meant?

Comment: could you post screenshots of graph before adding this code and after

Comment: All it does is it sets the value for X and Y axis but I wanted the axis numbering on the graph. Anyway, I used GNUPlot to plot a graph. Now, I am trying to LOG the graphical data using BOOST C++. I have posted a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282226/trying-to-find-a-way-to-log-graphical-data-in-opencv-boost on this. Please have a look and give me your valuable suggestion genius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to plot graphs in OpenCV. Here it goes,

From the https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sturkmen72/opencv_samples/master/plot-test.cpp link provided by Sturkmen, I took the codes and made it as my header file.

**plot.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

namespace cv
{
namespace plot
{
    //! @addtogroup plot
    //! @{

    class CV_EXPORTS_W Plot2d : public Algorithm
    {
    public:

        CV_WRAP virtual void setMinX(double _plotMinX) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setMinY(double _plotMinY) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setMaxX(double _plotMaxX) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setMaxY(double _plotMaxY) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setPlotLineWidth(int _plotLineWidth) = 0;
        /**
        * @brief Switches data visualization mode
        *
        * @param _needPlotLine if true then neighbour plot points will be connected by lines.
        * In other case data will be plotted as a set of standalone points.
        */
        CV_WRAP virtual void setNeedPlotLine(bool _needPlotLine) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setPlotLineColor(Scalar _plotLineColor) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setPlotBackgroundColor(Scalar _plotBackgroundColor) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setPlotAxisColor(Scalar _plotAxisColor) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setPlotGridColor(Scalar _plotGridColor) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setPlotTextColor(Scalar _plotTextColor) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setPlotSize(int _plotSizeWidth, int _plotSizeHeight) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setShowGrid(bool needShowGrid) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setShowText(bool needShowText) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void setGridLinesNumber(int gridLinesNumber) = 0;
        /**
        * @brief Sets the index of a point which coordinates will be printed on the top left corner of the plot (if ShowText flag is true).
        *
        * @param pointIdx index of the required point in data array.
        */
        CV_WRAP virtual void setPointIdxToPrint(int pointIdx) = 0;
        CV_WRAP virtual void render(OutputArray _plotResult) = 0;

        /**
        * @brief Creates Plot2d object
        *
        * @param data \f$1xN\f$ or \f$Nx1\f$ matrix containing \f$Y\f$ values of points to plot. \f$X\f$ values
        * will be equal to indexes of correspondind elements in data matrix.
        */
        CV_WRAP static Ptr<Plot2d> create(InputArray data);

        /**
        * @brief Creates Plot2d object
        *
        * @param dataX \f$1xN\f$ or \f$Nx1\f$ matrix \f$X\f$ values of points to plot.
        * @param dataY \f$1xN\f$ or \f$Nx1\f$ matrix containing \f$Y\f$ values of points to plot.
        */
        CV_WRAP static Ptr<Plot2d> create(InputArray dataX, InputArray dataY);
    };
    //! @}
}
}

namespace cv
{
namespace plot
{
    using namespace std;

    class Plot2dImpl : public Plot2d
    {
    public:

        Plot2dImpl(InputArray plotData)
        {
            Mat _plotData = plotData.getMat();
            //if the matrix is not Nx1 or 1xN
            if (_plotData.cols > 1 && _plotData.rows > 1)
                CV_Error(Error::StsBadArg, "ERROR: Plot data must be a 1xN or Nx1 matrix.\n");

            CV_Assert(_plotData.type() == CV_64F);

            //in case we have a row matrix than needs to be transposed
            if (_plotData.cols > _plotData.rows)
            {
                _plotData = _plotData.t();
            }

            plotDataY = _plotData;
            plotDataX = plotDataY * 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<plotDataY.rows; i++)
            {
                plotDataX.at<double>(i, 0) = i;
            }

            //calling the main constructor
            plotHelper(plotDataX, plotDataY);

        }

        Plot2dImpl(InputArray plotDataX_, InputArray plotDataY_)
        {
            Mat _plotDataX = plotDataX_.getMat();
            Mat _plotDataY = plotDataY_.getMat();
            //f the matrix is not Nx1 or 1xN
            if ((_plotDataX.cols > 1 && _plotDataX.rows > 1) || (_plotDataY.cols > 1 && _plotDataY.rows > 1))
                CV_Error(Error::StsBadArg, "ERROR: Plot data must be a 1xN or Nx1 matrix.\n");

            CV_Assert(_plotDataX.type() == CV_64F && _plotDataY.type() == CV_64F);

            //in case we have a row matrix than needs to be transposed
            if (_plotDataX.cols > _plotDataX.rows)
            {
                _plotDataX = _plotDataX.t();
            }
            if (_plotDataY.cols > _plotDataY.rows)
            {
                _plotDataY = _plotDataY.t();
            }

            plotHelper(_plotDataX, _plotDataY);
        }

        //set functions
        void setMinX(double _plotMinX)
        {
            plotMinX = _plotMinX;
            plotMinX_plusZero = _plotMinX;
        }
        void setMaxX(double _plotMaxX)
        {
            plotMaxX = _plotMaxX;
            plotMaxX_plusZero = _plotMaxX;
        }
        void setMinY(double _plotMinY)
        {
            plotMinY = _plotMinY;
            plotMinY_plusZero = _plotMinY;
        }
        void setMaxY(double _plotMaxY)
        {
            plotMaxY = _plotMaxY;
            plotMaxY_plusZero = _plotMaxY;
        }
        void setPlotLineWidth(int _plotLineWidth)
        {
            plotLineWidth = _plotLineWidth;
        }
        void setNeedPlotLine(bool _needPlotLine)
        {
            needPlotLine = _needPlotLine;
        }
        void setPlotLineColor(Scalar _plotLineColor)
        {
            plotLineColor = _plotLineColor;
        }
        void setPlotBackgroundColor(Scalar _plotBackgroundColor)
        {
            plotBackgroundColor = _plotBackgroundColor;
        }
        void setPlotAxisColor(Scalar _plotAxisColor)
        {
            plotAxisColor = _plotAxisColor;
        }
        void setPlotGridColor(Scalar _plotGridColor)
        {
            plotGridColor = _plotGridColor;
        }
        void setPlotTextColor(Scalar _plotTextColor)
        {
            plotTextColor = _plotTextColor;
        }
        void setPlotSize(int _plotSizeWidth, int _plotSizeHeight)
        {
            if (_plotSizeWidth > 400)
                plotSizeWidth = _plotSizeWidth;
            else
                plotSizeWidth = 400;

            if (_plotSizeHeight > 300)
                plotSizeHeight = _plotSizeHeight;
            else
                plotSizeHeight = 300;
        }
        void setShowGrid(bool _needShowGrid)
        {
            needShowGrid = _needShowGrid;
        }
        void setShowText(bool _needShowText)
        {
            needShowText = _needShowText;
        }
        void setGridLinesNumber(int _gridLinesNumber)
        {
            if (_gridLinesNumber <= 0)
                _gridLinesNumber = 1;
            gridLinesNumber = _gridLinesNumber;
        }
        void setPointIdxToPrint(int _cursorPos)
        {
            if (_cursorPos >= plotDataX.rows || _cursorPos < 0)
                _cursorPos = plotDataX.rows - 1;
            cursorPos = _cursorPos;
        }
        //render the plotResult to a Mat
        void render(OutputArray _plotResult)
        {
            //create the plot result
            _plotResult.create(plotSizeHeight, plotSizeWidth, CV_8UC3);
            plotResult = _plotResult.getMat();
            plotResult.setTo(plotBackgroundColor);

            int NumVecElements = plotDataX.rows;

            Mat InterpXdata = linearInterpolation(plotMinX, plotMaxX, 0, plotSizeWidth, plotDataX);
            Mat InterpYdata = linearInterpolation(plotMinY, plotMaxY, 0, plotSizeHeight, plotDataY);

            //Find the zeros in image coordinates
            Mat InterpXdataFindZero = linearInterpolation(plotMinX_plusZero, plotMaxX_plusZero, 0, plotSizeWidth, plotDataX_plusZero);
            Mat InterpYdataFindZero = linearInterpolation(plotMinY_plusZero, plotMaxY_plusZero, 0, plotSizeHeight, plotDataY_plusZero);

            int ImageXzero = (int)InterpXdataFindZero.at<double>(NumVecElements, 0);
            int ImageYzero = (int)InterpYdataFindZero.at<double>(NumVecElements, 0);

            double CurrentX = plotDataX.at<double>(cursorPos, 0);
            double CurrentY = plotDataY.at<double>(cursorPos, 0);

            drawAxis(ImageXzero, ImageYzero, CurrentX, CurrentY, plotAxisColor, plotGridColor);

            if (needPlotLine)
            {
                //Draw the plot by connecting lines between the points
                Point p1;
                p1.x = (int)InterpXdata.at<double>(0, 0);
                p1.y = (int)InterpYdata.at<double>(0, 0);

                for (int r = 1; r<InterpXdata.rows; r++)
                {
                    Point p2;
                    p2.x = (int)InterpXdata.at<double>(r, 0);
                    p2.y = (int)InterpYdata.at<double>(r, 0);

                    line(plotResult, p1, p2, plotLineColor, plotLineWidth, 8, 0);

                    p1 = p2;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int r = 0; r<InterpXdata.rows; r++)
                {
                    Point p;
                    p.x = (int)InterpXdata.at<double>(r, 0);
                    p.y = (int)InterpYdata.at<double>(r, 0);

                    circle(plotResult, p, 1, plotLineColor, plotLineWidth, 8, 0);
                }
            }
        }

    protected:

        Mat plotDataX;
        Mat plotDataY;
        Mat plotDataX_plusZero;
        Mat plotDataY_plusZero;
        const char * plotName;

        //dimensions and limits of the plot
        int plotSizeWidth;
        int plotSizeHeight;
        double plotMinX;
        double plotMaxX;
        double plotMinY;
        double plotMaxY;
        double plotMinX_plusZero;
        double plotMaxX_plusZero;
        double plotMinY_plusZero;
        double plotMaxY_plusZero;
        int plotLineWidth;
        bool needShowGrid;
        bool needShowText;
        int gridLinesNumber;
        int cursorPos;

        //colors of each plot element
        Scalar plotLineColor;
        Scalar plotBackgroundColor;
        Scalar plotAxisColor;
        Scalar plotGridColor;
        Scalar plotTextColor;

        //the final plot result
        Mat plotResult;

        //flag which enables/disables connection of plotted points by lines
        bool needPlotLine;

        void plotHelper(Mat _plotDataX, Mat _plotDataY)
        {
            plotDataX = _plotDataX;
            plotDataY = _plotDataY;

            int NumVecElements = plotDataX.rows;

            plotDataX_plusZero = Mat::zeros(NumVecElements + 1, 1, CV_64F);
            plotDataY_plusZero = Mat::zeros(NumVecElements + 1, 1, CV_64F);

            for (int i = 0; i<NumVecElements; i++)
            {
                plotDataX_plusZero.at<double>(i, 0) = plotDataX.at<double>(i, 0);
                plotDataY_plusZero.at<double>(i, 0) = plotDataY.at<double>(i, 0);
            }

            double MinX;
            double MaxX;
            double MinY;
            double MaxY;
            double MinX_plusZero;
            double MaxX_plusZero;
            double MinY_plusZero;
            double MaxY_plusZero;

            needPlotLine = true;

            //Obtain the minimum and maximum values of Xdata
            minMaxLoc(plotDataX, &MinX, &MaxX);

            //Obtain the minimum and maximum values of Ydata
            minMaxLoc(plotDataY, &MinY, &MaxY);

            //Obtain the minimum and maximum values of Xdata plus zero
            minMaxLoc(plotDataX_plusZero, &MinX_plusZero, &MaxX_plusZero);

            //Obtain the minimum and maximum values of Ydata plus zero
            minMaxLoc(plotDataY_plusZero, &MinY_plusZero, &MaxY_plusZero);

            //setting the min and max values for each axis
            plotMinX = MinX;
            plotMaxX = MaxX;
            plotMinY = MinY;
            plotMaxY = MaxY;
            plotMinX_plusZero = MinX_plusZero;
            plotMaxX_plusZero = MaxX_plusZero;
            plotMinY_plusZero = MinY_plusZero;
            plotMaxY_plusZero = MaxY_plusZero;

            //setting the default size of a plot figure
            setPlotSize(600, 400);

            //setting the default plot line size
            setPlotLineWidth(1);

            //setting default colors for the different elements of the plot
            setPlotAxisColor(Scalar(0, 0, 255));
            setPlotGridColor(Scalar(255, 255, 255));
            setPlotBackgroundColor(Scalar(0, 0, 0));
            setPlotLineColor(Scalar(0, 255, 255));
            setPlotTextColor(Scalar(255, 255, 255));
            setShowGrid(true);
            setShowText(true);
            setGridLinesNumber(10);
            setPointIdxToPrint(-1);
        }

        void drawAxis(int ImageXzero, int ImageYzero, double CurrentX, double CurrentY, Scalar axisColor, Scalar gridColor)
        {
            if (needShowText)
            {
                drawValuesAsText(0, ImageXzero, ImageYzero, 10, 20);
                drawValuesAsText(0, ImageXzero, ImageYzero, -20, 20);
                drawValuesAsText(0, ImageXzero, ImageYzero, 10, -10);
                drawValuesAsText(0, ImageXzero, ImageYzero, -20, -10);
                drawValuesAsText((format("X_%d = ", cursorPos) + "%g").c_str(), CurrentX, 0, 0, 40, 20);
                drawValuesAsText((format("Y_%d = ", cursorPos) + "%g").c_str(), CurrentY, 0, 20, 40, 20);
            }

            //Horizontal X axis and equispaced horizontal lines
            int LineSpace = cvRound(plotSizeHeight / (float)gridLinesNumber);
            int TraceSize = 5;
            drawLine(0, plotSizeWidth, ImageYzero, ImageYzero, axisColor);

            if (needShowGrid)
                for (int i = -plotSizeHeight; i<plotSizeHeight; i = i + LineSpace)
                {

                    if (i != 0)
                    {
                        int Trace = 0;
                        while (Trace<plotSizeWidth)
                        {
                            drawLine(Trace, Trace + TraceSize, ImageYzero + i, ImageYzero + i, gridColor);
                            Trace = Trace + 2 * TraceSize;
                        }
                    }
                }


            //Vertical Y axis
            drawLine(ImageXzero, ImageXzero, 0, plotSizeHeight, axisColor);
            LineSpace = cvRound(LineSpace * (float)plotSizeWidth / plotSizeHeight);

            if (needShowGrid)
                for (int i = -plotSizeWidth; i<plotSizeWidth; i = i + LineSpace)
                {

                    if (i != 0)
                    {
                        int Trace = 0;
                        while (Trace<plotSizeHeight)
                        {
                            drawLine(ImageXzero + i, ImageXzero + i, Trace, Trace + TraceSize, gridColor);
                            Trace = Trace + 2 * TraceSize;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

        Mat linearInterpolation(double Xa, double Xb, double Ya, double Yb, Mat Xdata)
        {

            Mat Ydata = Xdata * 0;

            for (int i = 0; i<Xdata.rows; i++)
            {

                double X = Xdata.at<double>(i, 0);
                Ydata.at<double>(i, 0) = int(Ya + (Yb - Ya)*(X - Xa) / (Xb - Xa));

                if (Ydata.at<double>(i, 0)<0)
                    Ydata.at<double>(i, 0) = 0;

            }

            return Ydata;
        }

        void drawValuesAsText(double Value, int Xloc, int Yloc, int XMargin, int YMargin)
        {

            char AxisX_Min_Text[20];
            double TextSize = 1;

            sprintf(AxisX_Min_Text, "%g", Value);
            Point AxisX_Min_Loc;
            AxisX_Min_Loc.x = Xloc + XMargin;
            AxisX_Min_Loc.y = Yloc + YMargin;

            putText(plotResult, AxisX_Min_Text, AxisX_Min_Loc, FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, TextSize, plotTextColor, 1, 8);
        }

        void drawValuesAsText(const char *Text, double Value, int Xloc, int Yloc, int XMargin, int YMargin)
        {

            char AxisX_Min_Text[20];
            int TextSize = 1;

            sprintf(AxisX_Min_Text, Text, Value);
            Point AxisX_Min_Loc;
            AxisX_Min_Loc.x = Xloc + XMargin;
            AxisX_Min_Loc.y = Yloc + YMargin;

            putText(plotResult, AxisX_Min_Text, AxisX_Min_Loc, FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, TextSize, plotTextColor, 1, 8);
        }


        void drawLine(int Xstart, int Xend, int Ystart, int Yend, Scalar lineColor)
        {

            Point Axis_start;
            Point Axis_end;
            Axis_start.x = Xstart;
            Axis_start.y = Ystart;
            Axis_end.x = Xend;
            Axis_end.y = Yend;

            line(plotResult, Axis_start, Axis_end, lineColor, plotLineWidth, 8, 0);
        }

    };

    Ptr<Plot2d> Plot2d::create(InputArray _plotData)
    {
        return Ptr<Plot2dImpl>(new Plot2dImpl(_plotData));

    }

    Ptr<Plot2d> Plot2d::create(InputArray _plotDataX, InputArray _plotDataY)
    {
        return Ptr<Plot2dImpl>(new Plot2dImpl(_plotDataX, _plotDataY));
    }
}
}
```

Now, the header file is ready. I added this **plot.h** to my cpp file.

Here is my Graph plotting function in OpenCV C++:

**Plot.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "plot.h"


int PlotGraph(Mat & data) {

//converting the Mat to CV_64F
data.convertTo(data, CV_64F);
Mat plot_result;

Ptr<plot::Plot2d> plot = plot::Plot2d::create(data);
plot->setPlotBackgroundColor(Scalar(50, 50, 50)); 
plot->setPlotLineColor(Scalar(50, 50, 255));
plot->render(plot_result);          

imshow("Graph", plot_result);
waitKey();

return 0;
}
```

so, we can create our own plot.h header file and plot graphs in OpenCV without using external libraries.

Comment: plot module still needs some improvements. you can share your remarks about using it in the [related issue page](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/1306)

Answer (score 7):

There is no plot support in OpenCV. You can use the [plot contrib module](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/plot), but it is very basic.

You could try Profactor CvPlot https://github.com/Profactor/cv-plot. (I am the developer). It is very easy to integrate, purely opencv based and can be extended with custom controls. This is how you can plot to a cv::Mat or show a diagram with an interactive viewer:

```cpp
#include <CvPlot/cvplot.h>
std::vector<double> x(20*1000), y1(x.size()), y2(x.size()), y3(x.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    x[i] = i * CV_2PI / x.size();
    y1[i] = std::sin(x[i]);
    y2[i] = y1[i] * std::sin(x[i]*50);
    y3[i] = y2[i] * std::sin(x[i]*500);
}
auto axes = CvPlot::makePlotAxes();
axes.create<CvPlot::Series>(x, y3, "-g");
axes.create<CvPlot::Series>(x, y2, "-b");
axes.create<CvPlot::Series>(x, y1, "-r");

//plot to a cv::Mat
cv::Mat mat = axes.render(300, 400);

//or show with interactive viewer
CvPlot::show("mywindow", axes);
```

[image: CvPlot]

You may also want to try [Leonardvandriel's cvplot](https://github.com/leonardvandriel/cvplot). It works similar but cannot be extended with custom drawables.

Comment: really helpful for plotting graphs using only opencv, thanks

Comment: Can it be used to put plots inside an image or a video? ( I mean inside each frame)

Comment: @KansaiRobot yes. e.g. video.read(frame); axes.render(frame(someRect)); https://github.com/Profactor/cv-plot/blob/master/CvPlot/inc/CvPlot/core/Axes.h

Answer (score 1):

In addition to needing the opencv_contrib modules, you need to change the line:

```
Ptr<plot::Plot2d> plot = plot::create2DPlot(data);
```

to

```
Ptr<plot::Plot2d> plot = plot::Plot2d::create(data);
```